# Identifying unique 2D arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following 3D np array:

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],
                 [3,1,2],
                 [2,1,3]],

                [[3,5,4],
                 [5,1,3],
                 [3,2,6]],

                [[1,2,3],
                 [3,1,2],
                 [2,1,3]],

                [[6,7,8],
                 [9,4,0],
                 [4,6,5]]])
```

This 3D array holds 4 2D arrays, but the actual **arr** holds hundreds of 2D arrays.

Now I locate the unique 2D arrays:

```
unq = np.unique(arr, axis = 0)
```

This correctly yields:

```
unq = array([[[1,2,3],
              [3,1,2],
              [2,1,3]],

             [[3,5,4],
              [5,1,3],
              [3,2,6]],

             [[6,7,8],
              [9,4,0],
              [4,6,5]]])
```

Here's the problem - I need to know the indices of arr found in unq.
In this example, I need to know that **unq holds  arr[0], arr[1], and arr[3].**   How can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), you can use the `return_index` flag to get the indices

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],
                 [3,1,2],
                 [2,1,3]],

                [[3,5,4],
                 [5,1,3],
                 [3,2,6]],

                [[1,2,3],
                 [3,1,2],
                 [2,1,3]],

                [[6,7,8],
                 [9,4,0],
                 [4,6,5]]])

unq, indices = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_index=True)

print(repr(indices))
```

which gives

```
array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Excellent.   Thanks, bfris